# Break the news: different meanings

Tags: meaning-in-context, collocations

Is the news necessarily bad or upsetting when someone *breaks the news*? Can this expression just mean that someone tells somebody something new?

Comment: It can go either way. *I can't wait to break the news about the new baby!*   or *That apartment has been taken already. Sorry to break the news.*

Comment: It can be either way, but it does imply that the news will have some sort of effect on the other person, so it's more than just telling something new.

Answer (score 2):

It may work both ways, but the expression is more commonly  used referring to bad news:

[break the news (to someone)](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/break+the+news):

> to tell someone some important news, usually bad news.
>
> - The doctor had to break the news to Jane about her husband's cancer. I hope that the doctor broke the news gently.

(McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs)

[break the news (to somebody)](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/american_english/news):

> to be the first to tell someone some bad news

(OLD)

[break the news](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/news):

> (=tell someone about something bad): I’m not looking forward to breaking the news to Dad.

(MacMillan Dictionary)

[break the news](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/break%20the%20news)

> : to tell (someone) bad news We tried to break the news to her gently.

(M-W)

Comment: An alternative point of view: https://writingexplained.org/idiom-dictionary/break-the-news - Summary: the phrase 'break the news' means to tell someone something new.